# Logic App - When connecting to on prem sql server: The gateway did not receive a response from 'Microsoft.Web' within the specified time period

Tags: sql-server, azure-logic-apps, onpremises-gateway

I have a sql server database which has around 15 stored procedures and 4,73,000 tables. Every month the number of tables gets increased by around 500.

I have created a logic app and added a sql server action to execute a stored procedure which is available in this database. But when I am trying to see if the logic app is pointed to correct stored procedure from the designer view it is giving me the below exception. Also see the below screen shot.

[image]

**The gateway did not receive a response from 'Microsoft.Web' within the specified time period.**

When I verified the logs of on prem data gateway, the below exception is logged there.

**Microsoft.Data.Mashup.MashupHostingException (0x80004005): Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation.**

I tried to increase the RAM of the VM to 16GB still having the same issue.

Can anyone help me out is fixing the issue. I am unable to find the cause of the issue as well.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are the gateway and sql server installed on same box?'

Comment: Yes! I am able to connect to other databases which are there in the same server, but unable to connect only to this.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on above point?

Comment: There was a typo in the above comment. Now edited!

Comment: Okay, and is the issue replicated when you use ssms? Or have you run profiler to check what is causing the database to consume so many resources? Looks like this particular database is busy

Comment: When I try to connect to the database using SSMS I am able to connect it. This database is not used by any other resources. I did not ran any profiler as of now.

Comment: Can anyone help me here ? I am still unable to find the solution.